# Java can't read that the character is a new line

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, char, newline

```
if (first == true) {
    x = input.read(); // input is a Reader
    nextCharacter = input.read();
    first = false;
}
else {
    x = nextCharacter;
    nextCharacter = input.read();
    charPosition++;
}

while (x == ' ' || x == '\n') {
    if (x == ' ') {
        x = nextCharacter;
    }
    else {
        x = nextCharacter;
    }
}
```

I am reading an input text file that has three blank lines. x reads character by character. x is equal to a new line so it suppose to go into the while loop but it does not. I debugged the code and printed out to check if x is holding a new line. It prints out x= 13, x = 10, x = 10. In all three of these cases, it skips the while loop.

Another method I tried:

```
while(x == '\n') {
    System.out.println("entered");
    x = nextCharacter;
}
```

When I write it in its own while loop it will enter the loop the second time (x = 10) but come back out the third time when x = 10. Which isn't suppose to happen it should stay in the loop until it hits the end of file (x = -1).

I also tried Character.toString((char) nextChar) == "\r\n" but that has the same result as the first one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is nextCharacter being set?

Comment: is `nextCharacter` a method you defined somewhere? Try to provide a short _compilable_ example which demonstrates the problem. As it is now, we can't test this code.

Comment: Please provide input + output

Comment: x reads the input using i.read() The input is a blank text file where I clicked enter two times. So the output should give me that the end of file is at line number 3. I used @Actimia suggestion to make it Character.isWhitespace(x) and it works except the line number comes out to be 5 instead of 3. I printed out some statements to see what x is and it says x = 13 x: 10 x: 13 x: 10

Comment: @Takendarkk nextCharacter is whatever is next in the input file.

Comment: @Kyle it is set above the while loop

Comment: And what actual code do you use to do that? You need to show us the exact code which is causing the problem. Until then we are just guessing.

Comment: @Takendarkk okay I edited the above code to show

Answer (score 1):

> I am reading an input text file that has three blank lines.

**The better way is read line by line and check each line whether it is empty or not.**

Sample code:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/abc.txt")));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(line);
            // do whatever you want to do with char array if needed
            // char[] arr=line.toCharArray();
        }
    }
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

"Blank line" may be a bit vague thing. Your "\r\n" attempt is close to the root cause of your issue (just strings should be compared via .equals instead of ==).

Another solution could be to create a proper input file where a new line is indeed just "\n" instead of "\r\n" (ascii codes 13, 10).

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use something like

```
while (Character.isWhitespace(x){
    // skip
}
```

The documentation for `Character.isWhitespace(char)`is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29).

Comment: I changed it to this and it works but the end of file should be line number 3 but it goes up to line number 5. It prints out x = 13
x: 10
x: 13
x: 10